# How to edit font and font size of VBA Outlook cell reference?

Tags: html, vba, outlook

How can I change the font and the font size of this cell reference?

```
With OutMail
.display
strbody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
```

In the e-mail it appears Times New Roman font size 12, but I wish to change it to Arial font size 10.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's nothing in Outlook called a cell. ...or are you referring to a cell in a table in a MailItem?

Comment: It seems like he's trying to send an e-mail from Excel

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your code, and set a desired size as a number and desired font style like "Calibri" or "Verdana:

```
With strbody
     .Font.Name = "Calibri"
     .Font.Size = 10
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I receive an error code saying "With object must be user-defined type, Object, or Variant". I tried to google it but it is very confusing! Sorry for my question..

Comment: Do you have strbody declared as string? Would be easier to see your full code. The method is correct.